# When should you use "prototype" during object augmentation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I'm confused about the notion of "prototype" in javascript.

When I'm defining an object both of the following seem to work:

```
myObject = {};
myObject.prototype.method1 = function() { ... };
myObject.prototype.method2 = function() { ... };
myObject.prototype.method3 = function() { ... };
```

and...

```
myObject = {};
myObject.method1 = function() { ... };
myObject.method2 = function() { ... };
myObject.method3 = function() { ... };
```

Could anyone shed some light on this?  What exactly is the difference between these two ways of creating an object and why would I choose one over the other?  (I have this feeling in my gut it's important...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the `prototype` property only on [*Constructor Functions*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Creating_New_Objects/Using_a_Constructor_Function), not in *object instances*, for example:

```
function Test () {}
Test.prototype.method1 = function () {/*...*/};

var obj = new Test();
```

The `prototype` property of constructor functions, is used by the `new` operator, when it creates our new object instance.

All native objects have a hidden link, that builds up the prototype chain.

This hidden link between objects is the `[[Prototype]]` internal property, and the `new` operator is the only one that can set it.

In the above example, the `obj` is associated internally with it's constructor prototype, the `method1` is accessible from `obj`, but it doesn't exists physically on this object, that method exists on the `Test.prototype` object, and it's retrieved through the *prototype chain*, e.g.:

```
typeof obj.method1; // "function"
obj.hasOwnProperty('method1'); // false
obj.method1 === Test.prototype.method1; // true
```

On object instances, assigning a `prototype` property is meaningless, it will be taken just as any other property name:

```
var myObject = {};
myObject.prototype = "foo";
myObject.bar = "bar";

// myObject is simply {"prototype":"foo","bar":"bar"}
```

Comment: Would add that many times there will be internally added methods to each instance inside the Constructor function via:  this.fn = function(){...};  which is useful for having private instance variables that are accessed by instance methods.

Answer (score 1):

Second way adds methods only to this object. First way makes it available for other objects created with `new` with this "type".